# Am trying to convert game controls from keyboard keys to buttons on the page

Tags: javascript, html

i have a tetris game that is controlled when arrow key on the keyboard is
pressed, but i want to actually place these responsibility on 4 HTML buttons instead. here is the
code working so far:

````
```document.body.onkeydown = function( e ) {
    var keys = {
        37: 'left',
        39: 'right',
        40: 'down',
        38: 'rotate',
        32: 'drop'
    };
    if ( typeof keys[ e.keyCode ] != 'undefined' ) {
        keyPress( keys[ e.keyCode ] );
        render();
    }
};```
````

**And here is the the keyPress function that handles the movement and direction of the object
based on which key code is pressed. the render() function is the function that draws the game objects: **

```
     switch ( key ) {
         case "left":
             if ( valid( -1 ) ) {
                 --currentX;
                 xPush.play();
             }
             break;
         case 'right':
             if ( valid( 1 ) ) {
                 ++currentX;
                 xPush.play();
             }
             break;
         case 'down':
             if ( valid( 0, 1 ) ) {
                 ++currentY;
                 xPush.play();
             }
             break;
         case 'rotate':
             var rotated = rotate( current );
             if ( valid( 0, 0, rotated ) ) {
                 current = rotated;
             }
             break;
         case 'drop':
             while( valid(0, 1) ) {
                 ++currentY;
             }
             tick();
             break;
     }
 }
```

please i want to add 4 HTML buttons to do the control instead of keyboard keys/ keys code. Thank you all

Comment: you can add either `<button>` or an `<input type="button">` to the HTML

Comment: What is the question? You have a pure function that works on direction. So you can just do `.onClick(() => keyPress('left'))` for left button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need just to replace the `onkeydown` function of yours.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".action");
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    keypress(button.getAttribute("data-action"));
    // render();
  })
})

function keypress(key) {
  console.log ("key " + key + " was pressed");
}
```

```html
<button class="action" data-action="left">left</button>
<button class="action" data-action="right">right</button>
<button class="action" data-action="down">down</button>
<button class="action" data-action="rotate">rotate</button>
<button class="action" data-action="drop">drop</button>
```

Comment: #Rajesh please can i then use key  in my swich case statemen?

Comment: IT goldman then can i use switch case on key?

Comment: yes as far as `keypress` function, it doesn't care from where it got its `key` parameter.

Comment: Waoooohh it works, am very grateful to you all. thanks for using the time to assist me, am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".action");
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    keypress(button.getAttribute("data-action"));
    // render();
  })
})

function keypress(key) {
  console.log ("key " + key + " was pressed");
}
```

Comment: I just did as you said, I replaced my document.body.onKeyDown function and replace it with yours.